# How to convert an object to data.frame?

Tags: r, class, dataframe

I need a data.frame for some analysis. The origin of the data is a CSV file, which I have imported into R with the following code

```
presa_preparado <- read_delim ("presa_preparado.csv",
     ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_types = cols(
     CodigoPlaca = col_character(),
     EDAD = col_factor(levels = c("0","1")), 
     FAT = col_factor(levels = c("0", "1")), 
     HORA = col_character(),
     HoraDesde = col_character(), 
     HoraHasta = col_character(), 
     HoraTXT = col_character(),
     ID = col_integer(), 
     MUSCLE = col_character(),
     PLACA = col_character(), 
     RECAP = col_factor(levels = c("0", "1")), 
     SEX = col_factor(levels = c("0", "1", "2")), 
     VUELTA = col_integer(),
     year = col_skip()), 
   trim_ws = TRUE)
```

The needed object is a data.frame but what I get is

```
class(presa_preparado)
[1] "spec_tbl_df" "tbl_df"      "tbl"         "data.frame"
```

How that can be transformed into a data.frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that `presa_preparado`, the object holding your `.csv` data, is a `tibble` `data.frame`. You should be able to convert it to a `data.frame` by calling `as.data.frame(presa_preparado)`. Alternatively, you can use `readr::read_csv(file)` or `data.table::fread(file, data.table = F)` for faster performance.